# Using Squeryl transform a subquery which return rows in a list

Tags: scala, squeryl

Let's say I have this tables in MySQL:

```
Courses: id, name

Students: id, name

CoursesStudents: idCourse, idStudent
```

I can do:

```
SELECT c.id, cs.idStudent
FROM Courses C, CoursesStudents cs
WHERE c.id = cs.idCourse
```

For every course I will get some rows of the students that attend that course.

How can I transform the query to return just one row per course, and in the second column
the list of id's students? Something like:

```
course1 st1, st2, st3
course2 st4, st5
course3 st7
...
```

If it is posible, how can I do that using squeryl library in Scala?

Edit:

I found how to do it in plain SQL using "GROUP_CONCAT":

```
SELECT c.id, GROUP_CONCAT(cs.idStudent)
FROM Courses C, CoursesStudents cs
WHERE c.id = cs.idCourse
GROUP BY c.id
```